# Calculate principal curvature from two surface tangents

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I understand that principal curvature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature comes from the eigenvalues of the matrix made of the 2nd derivatives.

Given the two (orthogonal) surfaces tangents $X_u, X_v$ (a surface defined over uv parametric space), for example:
$$
X_u= \frac{\partial X}{\partial u}= \begin{bmatrix}
x(u) \\
y(u) \\
z(u)
\end{bmatrix}  \;\;\;\;\;e.g.
\begin{bmatrix}
u^2-v^2 \\
2u+2v \\
3u-v^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
X_v= \frac{\partial X}{\partial v}= \begin{bmatrix}
a(v) \\
b(v) \\
c(v)
\end{bmatrix}\;\;\;\;\;e.g.
\begin{bmatrix}
u^2+v^2 \\
v-u^2 \\
v^2-u
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I can easily find the 2nd derivatives: $X_{uu}, X_{uv},X_{vu},X_{vv}$, e.g.
$$
X_{uu}= \begin{bmatrix}
2u\\
2 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but how to write the Hessian matrix for principal curvature and  principal direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your examples of $X_u$ and $X_v$ can't occur (note that $X_{uv}\ne X_{vu}$).

You need more information than just the second partial derivatives to get the principal directions and curvatures. You need to calculate the second fundamental form matrix 
$$\mathbf{II} = \begin{bmatrix} X_{uu}\cdot n & X_{uv}\cdot n \\ X_{vu}\cdot n & X_{vv}\cdot n \end{bmatrix},$$
where $n$ is the unit normal vector, the first fundamental form matrix 
$$\mathbf{I} = \begin{bmatrix} X_u\cdot X_u & X_u\cdot X_v \\ X_v\cdot X_u & X_v\cdot X_v\end{bmatrix},$$
and then calculate the matrix of the shape operator by taking $\mathbf I^{-1}\mathbf{II}$. This is the matrix whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors you want to find.

By the way, you may find my freely downloadable differential geometry text (see my profile) of use.